# Create Method attempting to insert FK as ID from form

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to insert new data into one of my tables, and I'm getting Identity Insert errors, even though I'm never actually setting an ID at all.

I can fix this with a bandaid, but I'd like to understand why exactly this is happening and what the best practice is

If I set Id to 0 before adding to DbContext, it works properly, but I don't understand where my Id is being set at all.

Here's my model:

```cs
public class Question : BaseModel
{
    public QuestionGroup QuestionGroup { get; set; }

    public int QuestionGroupId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Question Text")]
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class BaseModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(AutoGenerateField = false), JsonIgnore]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [Display(AutoGenerateField = false), JsonIgnore]
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my relevant controller code: (if I uncomment setting the Id to 0, it works fine)

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Question question)
{
    //question.Id = 0;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(question);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Details", "QuestionGroups", new { id = 
        question.QuestionGroupId });
    }
    await PopulateId(question.QuestionGroupId);
    return View(question);
}
```

Here's my form:

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Create" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <input asp-for="QuestionGroupId" type="hidden" 
        value="@ViewBag.QuestionGroupId"/>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="QuestionText" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="QuestionText" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="QuestionText" class="text-danger></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Type" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Type" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Type" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

This gives me the following error:

```
SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Questions' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

Which makes sense, as when I debug this is what I see:
[image]

Any guidance is appreciated

Comment: Maybe the Question class accidentally contains something like Id = QuestionGroupId? And what is this: _context.Add(question);?

Comment: @feihoa There's nothing else in my question class besides namespace etc stuff.

Comment: You have Id which is not 0 before _context.SaveChangesAsync() or after? I guess before, so do you use javascript to submit the form?

Comment: @feihoa The debug is from the first line on the post method, so it is not 0 before  _context.SaveChangesAsync().

There's nothing else that would affect the form outside of the form html code I posted. I'm really scratching my head about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, my problem was actually in my get method for create. Here's the broken code:

```cs
// GET: Questions/Create
        public IActionResult Create(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null) {
                return NotFound();
            }
            PopulateId(id);
            return View();
        }
```

The fix:

```cs
// GET: Questions/Create
        public IActionResult Create(int? questionGroupId)
        {
            if (questionGroupId== null) {
                return NotFound();
            }
            PopulateId(questionGroupId);
            return View();
        }
```

Since the default startup had this template:

```cs
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

**In conclusion:**

This was quite a simple mistake, as I was using poor naming. Default create get methods don't have an ID, but since I needed to do some stuff with the parent object on the page, I had to pass it to my view, and .Net was setting my questionId (child) to the questionGroupId (parent).

I hope this helps anyone else who runs into this issue.

Thanks to commenters for the help

Answer (score 1):

Very strange. All I can advise is just try to make Id property not auto to find out where does it set from looking at call stack.

```
private int _id;
public int Id 
{ 
   get { return _id; }
   set { _id = value; } 
}
```

And set a breakpoint on line with 'set'

Answer (score 0):

I tried to re-generate your errro by creating an `ASP.NET Core` project using these codes:

```
public class BaseModel
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}

public class Question : BaseModel
{
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

//Startup.cs
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
        {
            options.UseSqlite(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
            );
        });


//Home Controller
    public IActionResult Test()
    {
        _applicationDbContext.Questions.Add(new Question
        {
            Id = 0, //Changing this value affects the behaviour of the application
            QuestionText = "Question text"
        });

        _applicationDbContext.SaveChanges();
        return View(_applicationDbContext.Questions.ToList());
    }
```

But, I was not able to re-generate your same error. While `Id` (in the `Test()` method) is not set or is set equal to 0, it works. If I set to a number greater than 0, for example 100, it works for first time but fails in next runs with this error message:

> SQLite Error 19: 'UNIQUE constraint failed: Questions.Id'

As you see, I am using SQLite here. The generated migration is as follows:

```
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Questions",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                CreatedAt = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                UpdatedAt = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                QuestionText = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                Type = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Questions", x => x.Id);
            });
    }
```

Here, `Id` field is created as an identity field.

What can I conclude is that your `Id` field is created as an `identity` field which is set automatically by database. So you should not set a specific value for it. Maybe somewhere in your processing a none zero value is set. As @feihoa says, a break point at the point and a debugging session may help.

Your configuration code in `startup.cs`, your migration code and infromation about database type that you are using may help if the problem still exists.